# Data from database in href link echos site url

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using a foreach loop in codeigniter, I am trying to display website links from database in href html tags, But it echos the siteurl instead of linking to the website link.

```
<?php foreach ($as as $a): {


<li>

<strong>Web</strong>

 <a href="<?php echo $a['website']; ?>" target="_blank" rel="nowfollow"><? 
 php echo $a['website']; ?></a></div>

   </li>

<?php }endforeach; ?>
```

for example www.instagram.com was in the database it will link similar to this 
    `localhost/site/view/www.instagram.com/p/BgHH1TyDqvp/` instead of just linking too `www.instagram.com`

Comment: Yeah, your PHP syntax is all wrong.

Comment: Oh wow thanks for your helpful comment. This solve the issue. right here, Also this is MVC not vanilla php so I would hope my syntax would look incorrect. Maybe you missed that part at the very top.

Comment: Yeah, it's still wrong, regardless. You can't just have a foreach start dumping out plain HTML. Wrap it in some echo tags. Also, there shouldn't be an `:` after declaring your foreach.

Comment: even echoing html tags and concatenating the variable the url still continues to use the site url for the link first localhost/site/view.   Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that if the protocol (http or https) isn't at the front of an external link then it'll handle it as a relative path. If I know there's a chance of an external link in the database I'll check for the protocol and add it if needed.

Updated Code

```
<?php foreach($as as $a) :
    // Check if we have the protocol
    $pro = (substr($a['website'], 0, 4) != 'http' ? 'https://' : '');        
    ?>
    <li>
        <strong>Web</strong>
        <a href="<?= $pro . $a['website'] ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
            <?= $a['website'] ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is based off memory and haven't tested this specific code block.

I don't claim this to be the best way to handle this, but has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am still getting use the MVC environment, By butting https:// in front of the link in the database this solved it. Have not tried you code yet but thanks.